# Q:Mockito - Using @Mock and @Autowired

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'd like to test a service class which has two other service classes like as below using `Mockito`.

```
@Service
public class GreetingService {

    private final Hello1Service hello1Service;
    private final Hello2Service hello2Service;

    @Autowired
    public GreetingService(Hello1Service hello1Service, Hello2Service hello2Service) {
        this.hello1Service = hello1Service;
        this.hello2Service = hello2Service;
    }

    public String greet(int i) {
        return hello1Service.hello(i) + " " + hello2Service.hello(i);
    }
}

@Service
public class Hello1Service {

    public String hello(int i) {

        if (i == 0) {
            return "Hello1.";
        }

        return "Hello1 Hello1.";
    }
}

@Service
public class Hello2Service {

    public String hello(int i) {

        if (i == 0) {
            return "Hello2.";
        }

    return "Hello2 Hello2.";
    }
}
```

I know how to mock `Hello1Service.class` and `Hello2Service.class` with `Mockito` like as below.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class GreetingServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private GreetingService greetingService;

    @Mock
    private Hello1Service hello1Service;

    @Mock
    private Hello2Service hello2Service;

    @Test
    public void test() {

        when(hello1Service.hello(anyInt())).thenReturn("Mock Hello1.");
        when(hello2Service.hello(anyInt())).thenReturn("Mock Hello2.");

        assertThat(greetingService.greet(0), is("Mock Hello1. Mock Hello2."));
    }
}
```

I'd like to mock `Hello1Service.class` and inject `Hello2Service.class` using `@Autowired` like as below.
I tired to use `@SpringBootTest` but it did not work.
Is there a better way?

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class GreetingServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private GreetingService greetingService;

    @Mock
    private Hello1Service hello1Service;

    @Autowired
    private Hello2Service hello2Service;

    @Test
    public void test() {

        when(hello1Service.hello(anyInt())).thenReturn("Mock Hello1.");
        assertThat(greetingService.greet(0), is("Mock Hello1. Hello2."));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to inject dependency with some functionality to be formed then use `@Spy`.
You don't to load Spring Container and use `@Autowired`.

```
@Spy
private Hello2Service hello2Service=new Hello2Service();
```

You can read more detail about **Mock vs Spy** ;

https://dzone.com/articles/mockito-mock-vs-spy-in-spring-boot-tests

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works.
If Hello2Service has a jpa repository, how should I instantiate Hello2Service?  like    `public class public class Hello2Service { @Autowired HelloRepository helloRepository;...`

`@Repository interface HelloRepository extends JpaRepository...`

Answer (score 2):

You can change with Spy for real object instead of Mock. 
Test code will be like this;

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class GreetingServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private GreetingService greetingService;

    @Mock
    private Hello1Service hello1Service;

    @Spy
    private Hello2Service hello2Service;

    @Test
    public void test() {

        when(hello1Service.hello(anyInt())).thenReturn("Mock Hello1.");
        assertThat(greetingService.greet(0), is("Mock Hello1. Hello2."));
    }
}
```